# Modal over iframe won't allow drags

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-dropzone, react-player

I have a modal that's over an iframe video that has a dropzone that helps me upload documents. See [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/pjz2xxlkv7). The [dropzone](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/) works perfectly when it is not overlaying the iframe.

I'm wondering what needs to happen for the corresponding browser events to correctly register on the general parent page document rather than the iframe document? Or if any of you have any ideas on how to make this work I'd love your assistance. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried disabling or hiding the iframe when the Modal is up? Or used a different web browser?

Comment: Demo works for me. Can drop on either blue box. Hard to see the file name text on top of iframe due to contrast but it is there